# Form post parameters ending up in URL

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

This is going to be a difficult one to explain but basically I have an angular application with a login form which runs a function on submit which sends an ajax request to the server to do the login.

Now, I'm not using ng-submit but hijacking the normal submit attribute like this:

```
<form my-form submit="controllername.doSubmit()">
```

I then have an angular directive called "my-form" which uses {require: 'form'} in it's definition object and then does this in the postLink function:

```
element.bind('submit', function(event)
{
    // Removed for brevity

    scope.$apply(scope.submit);
});
```

So, basically this form submit stuff was written a long time ago and does a lot of other stuff like triggering form validation and stuff by default so I don't wnt to rewrite any of this or go back to using ng-submit. Aside form anything else I have a few big apps using this code which would need to change a lot.

Anyway, it all works fine on the surface but if I fill in the log in form and then do some other stuff (including filling in other forms set up the same way) and then leave my laptop for a few days and come back to the page, somehow all the form data has been added into the URL bar, after the ?? and before the # including the password in plain view!

Not sure why this doesn't happen straight away, ony after un-sleeping the PC, and not always. The other weird thing is that the names of the parameters are not the original ones (email, password) but the names of the parameters of the first form currently on the page (actionStatus, required), so Chrome is obviously getting very confused.

My instinct tells me that when the form is submitted, the formData is being stored somewhere for later because I'm not cancelling the default action of the form correctly when I'm running my javascript function and because it's a single page application that formData never leaves the memory. It's then thinking it's gone to a new page and putting that data in the URl, but it's getting the names wrong because the forms on the page has changed.

Sorry, I can't provide more code, just a fairly wooly description but I don't know what else to say really, it's all very strange.

Comment: Something on your page is doing a GET request. Without seeing all the code that's making AJAX calls, then it's difficult to say where your problem lies though. Look through all of the scripts on your page for anything that's making an AJAX call of any sort, and look for setTimeout calls, etc.

Comment: I'm using Angular's $http.get() a lot, but not when the login form is shown. So does an ajax get request put your formData in the URL under some circumstances?

Comment: Any GET request will have the parameters in the querystring of the URL. Not necessarily visibly so, of course, depending on the request, but if you're making any kind of GET request, and you're passing things like passwords, then they will potentially visible to end users, AJAX or otherwise.

Comment: When I send the login form to the server I'm using $http.post() to do that so I'm not sure how the login form data is ending up as the data in a get request anywhere.

Comment: Look at your Network requests in your console. And you can see all the requests that have been made from that page. Leave it open, if you think something is being delayed and check it the next day. From the console, you'll be able to see whether they are GET or POST, or whatever, and the parameters that have been submitted.

Comment: Thanks ManoDestra. This seems to have been a waste of time though (see my answer) so apologies for that.

Comment: No problem. Glad to be of some assistance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally have an answer to this and the answer is totally unexpected.

I use a plugin called browserSync to sync multiple browsers I'm testing on and it had a feature called form syncing switched on.

I had chrome open and when I opened up another browser (typically in the morning when the computer first woke up) I had to log in and because they were on different pages it was copying my login details from Firefox into the first form it found in my existing chrome window. It was also putting the contents of Firefox's login form into chrome's URL.

Crazy.